Good books about random walks on groups.
I am about to start writing an undergraduate essay that will be split into two parts - the first part being an introduction to random walks and the second part being about random walks on finite groups.
I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations for books/articles on these topics that don't rely on having a background in measure theory.

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158210/reference-requested-random-walk-on-groups. I think you may want to look at the book on Representation theory of finite groups of Steinberg. Chapter 11 on random walk on groups is readable (to me) and the author just uses algebraic tools. There are other recommedation in the link.
